# Is the PUSH token sufficient to send a notification to a server via GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

There is a server sends a notification to an App using `GCM`, I want to send a notification to the same server as well through `GCM`, but I do not have the information that were available 
to send the notification to the App. I mean I do not have `Server Key` and such information, the only thing I have is the `Push Token`.

Given only the `Push Token`, can I send a notification the server using `GCM`?

Comment: No, you can't. You must have the server key.

Comment: so, when i have the server key, then i can send notification to GCM and then GCM will forward that notification to the server right?